# How to understand this magic: "array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, array given"?

Tags: php, php-7.2

Here is my simple code:

```
$item['suppliers'] = array_values($item['suppliers']);
```

And here is PHP error log:

```
[22-May-2019 13:05:23 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, array given in /var/www/xxx/Controller.php on line 242
[22-May-2019 13:07:06 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, array given in /var/www/xxx/Controller.php on line 242
[22-May-2019 13:07:45 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, array given in /var/www/xxx/Controller.php on line 242
```

[image]

Comment: as it says on the tin, $item['suppliers'] isn't an array

Comment: try this `$item['suppliers'] = array_values($item);`

Comment: @ZainFarooq And for what? I need exactly ```$item['suppliers']```

Comment: It might be that `$item['suppliers']` is some string instead of an array

Comment: `print_r($item['suppliers'])` and show us the results

Answer (score 0):

**$item['suppliers'] might be an item in an array but not an array which is why the error is thrown.**

You should put your array name inside **array_values()** function.

So Correct code will be:

***$item['suppliers'] = array_values($item);***

Comment: No. No. No. I have $item['suppliers'], I have $item['total'], I have $item['min]. So I need exactly $item['suppliers']. I can't past var_dump() response, but $item is a simple array of arrays and $item['suppliers'] is a simple array of arrays.

Comment: if $item['suppliers'] is an array of an array, then you can at least let us know which item of an array $item['suppliers'] you want to pull out in new $item['suppliers'].

Hope you are understanding the mechanism of array_values.

array_values expect an array (only) as a parameter, not an array of an array or only single value or string anything.
So you have to pass an array only as a parameter.

Comment: I want to get the same array, but without keys. This is what this function is for.

Comment: Until you provide dummy data and the format of the data you want, it's hard to explain. But just to answer your query, array_values works for fetching values from single array, not for fetching values from multidimensional array, so you to pass single array to array values() by traversing your $item['suppliers'] in loop may be.

Answer (score 0):

$item['suppliers'] is not array .array_values require array parameter .

```
if(is_array($item['suppliers'])
{
$item['suppliers'] = array_values($item['suppliers);

}
```

Maybe u want do as below

```
$item['suppliers']=array_values($item);
```